# Авторизация через соц. сети в приложении

Tags: php, api, oauth2

Всем привет.
Вопрос думаю уже должен иметь какие-то best practics, но не нашел.

У меня есть сайт, у него есть АПИ, есть мобильное приложение, которое общается с этим АПИ. Запросы пользователей проверяются по access_token Oauth2.

На сайте есть авторизация через соц. сети, там все просто и понятно.

Как сделать авторизацию через соц. сети в мобильном приложении? Ведь в случае успешной авторизации, необходимо завести учетную запись в бд сайта.

Пока в голове 2 варианта.

1. Авторизация в webView на стороне сайта. В приложении открывается страница сайта авторизации, после успешного логина имитирую обращение по oauth, генерирую access_token и refresh_token и делаю редирект с этими значениями.
2. Авторизация напрямую в приложении. Происходит авторизация, затем приложение вызывает метод регистрации пользователя на сайте через АПИ.

1 вариант кажется каким-то костылем. 2 вариант тоже, создается какой-то дополнительный метод регистрации без пароля, который открыт всем снаружи, думаю это не лучшее решение.

Подскажите, наверняка уже кто-то решал уже эту задачу и нашел идеальный вариант:)

Comment: `1 вариант кажется каким-то костылем` - так и есть. Webview ненадежен

Comment: Я бы посмотрел в сторону sdk. Сейчас он у всех соц. сетей есть

Comment: А как sdk поможет. Авторизуюсь, а дальше то что? 2 вариант?

Comment: Да, вам в любом случае на сервер отправлять(токен и другие данные).

Comment: `создается какой-то дополнительный метод регистрации без пароля` - можете на сервере в соц. сеть отправить еще один запрос на проверку токена.

Comment: `А как sdk поможет` - в разы улучшит юзабилити. Все будет делаться в приложении